# Embed .net treeview into vba?

Tags: .net, ms-access, vba, treeview

In an ms-access vba form, I am using a treeview control which is not rich enough for my purposes (class MSComctlLib.TreeCtrl.2). I found documentation on a newer and better treeview control, but this is a .net version.
I know virtually nothing about .net, but I wonder whether it is possible to embed this .net treeview into vba, so that I can use it in my forms.
Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose the .net control as an activex control:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1256/Exposing-Windows-Forms-Controls-as-ActiveX-control

There probably is another way to do this using visual studio tools for office.

Comment: Sounds good! And - although it will probably take me some time to get it all working, I am accepting this answer as the right one. I am pretty sure that I will not have to undo that :-).